# Best known bounds on certain exponential sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

What are the best bounds currently known for the following exponential sum:

$$\sum_{x < p \le 2x} e(\alpha p^k)$$

for values of $\alpha$ far from a rational with small denominator. ($p$ refers to a prime in this case)

In particular, I am interested in such bounds for $k = 9$.

The following gives some bounds: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1156345592, but have these bounds been improved since then?

EDIT: I am also interested in such bounds assuming GRH.

Comment: My first idea was to tell you about Kumchev's paper, but then I saw your link exactly leads there. I think you can get the best answer to your question by asking Kumchev himself.

Comment: Kumchev has a second paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.0201v1.pdf, where he has obtained slight improvements when $k\geq 8$ (see Theorem 4 of that paper).